# How to manage 2 for 1 sale pricing on iOS / iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm wanting to sell a consumable product in my app, and arbitrarily offer it for sale as a 2 for 1 deal.

### Example

Let's say I have a consumable product: **50 Proton Pills for $0.99** (Tier 1).

I'm wanting to periodically, for a set amount of time, instead offer **100 Proton Pills for $0.99**.

My strategy for making this work was to have 2 different products in iTunes Connect.

```
Product 1: 50 Proton Pills - Tier 1
Product 2: 100 Proton Pills - Tier 1
```

Normally, Product 1 would be set `Cleared for Sale Yes` and Product 2 would be set `Cleared for Sale No`. When I want a 2 for 1 sale, I'd simply reverse these settings.

My app would always request both products from the app store, and whichever one comes back would be displayed to the user for purchase.

### My Problem

In testing, ALL products are getting returned when they're requested, even if they've been set as `Cleared for Sale No`.

Without being able to test this feature, I'm not keen on just releasing my app and hoping for the best.

### My Questions

1) Is there a way to actually test adding and removing products from sale in iTunes Connect, so that they aren't returned if set `Cleared for Sale No`?

2) If answer to 1 is no, is there another way to achieve and test what I want (i.e. a 2 for 1 sale)?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two products:

- Product 1 - 50 coins. Normal price. Usually active.
- Product 2 - 100 coins. Same price as Product 1, but double the coins. Usually inactive.

Product 2 is a discount that means 2 x 1 Product 1.

You could remove Product 1 and introduce Product 2 in the list of your Products for Sale, according to Apple's guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html

The only concern here is that IAP availability changes take some time (hours, from 1 hour to 24 usually) to apply. So if you change the availability, you (i.e. the app) will not see the Status change till some hours later (until Apple's Servers have replicated the information).

Comment: So there's no way in iTunes Connect to make something either available or unavailable for sale? If this is the case, what is the purpose of the "Cleared for Sale" parameter?

Comment: No. I understand now. You were right. I thought you meant Product 1, Product 2 and a (Product 1 & Product 2) sale (discount). I will correct my answer.

Comment: I don't mind if there's a bit of lag, as I set up my app to check if sale item is returned, if so present to user and ignore normal price time. My problem is that it seems both items always get returned during testing. Is this just a time issue? Should I wait a day after changing items before testing?

Comment: I have not implemented that, so I cannot give an answer with experience here. The normal situation is that it will return items correctly. Some other implementations, such as the link to rate the app, don't work till the app has been approved, so you have to rely on Apple's documentation that it will work as expected.